# How to display multiple markers on a map

Tags: android, google-maps

Iam creating and appliaction in which i want to display two markers on map , 1st marker will display on the starting latitude and longitude in map and second will display on the destination latitude and longitude , so i am stuck here can any help me out to sort

Comment: What have you done so far? Which is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use MapView Overlays. Here's the documentation, and a sample:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/mapOverlayDemo.html